# Translation of "to be confronted with"

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова

For instance

> I confronted him with the fact, that I've seen him entering the building.
>   He was confronted with the fact, that somebody has seen him entering the building

How'd that be put into Russian?
Would it be possible to use `столкнуться` (at least in the second case)?
There seems to be the word `конфронтировать`, but I don't know how it is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPD:** biggvsdiccvs прав, "ставить перед фактом" означает "не оставить другого выбора". Например человек собирался поехать в отпуск в Чехию или в Польшу, а его поставили перед фактом, что поедет он с детьми к теще в Шушенское.

Все-таки наверное можно здесь употребить "был поставлен перед фактом", если человек пытался выбрать альтернативные объяснения тому где он был и что он делал, а его лишили выбора и поставили перед фактом того, что уже известно что он делал на самом деле. Но это очень редкий случай и рекомендовать всегда переводить "confronted with the fact" с помощью "поставить перед фактом" все-таки нельзя.

---

> Я поставил его перед фактом, что я видел его входящим в здание.
>
> Он был поставлен перед фактом, что его видели входящим в здание.

Слово "конфронтировать" означает "противостоять, противоборствовать" и здесь не подходит.

"Столкнулся с фактом" - так можно сказать, но мне кажется что здесь может не подойти. В принципе "столкнулся с фактом" означает "обнаружил, что":

> Он обнаружил, что его видели входящим в здание.

---

Я специально заменил "кто-то видел" на "видели входящим", так как если говорят что "вас кто-то видел", то говорящий скорее всего знает кто видел.

С другой стороны, если стало понятно по косвенным признакам, что его видели входящим в здание (например - полиция окружила здание чтобы поймать преступника, который тайно в это здание вошел). Тогда не понятно кто видел, как он входил в здание и можно сказать "кто-то видел".

Comment: A small correction: no native speaker in their right mind would use "видели входящим в здание". There is a much better construction for that, typically used in situations "someone perceived someone else doing something": "Я видел, как он входил здание", "кто-то видел, как он входил вздание". "Был поставлен перед фактов" sounds stilted, too — maybe a police official would use it in an attempt to sound smart, but not in normal writing or a usual person's speech. Generally, participles in Russian are not as ubiquitous as in English.

Comment: @Shady_arc I’m a native speaker, hopefully being in my right mind, and I claim the wording “видели входящим в здание” is fine.

Comment: the construction with participle is correct, but rarelier used.

Comment: Of course, it is correct. It is just atypical unless you specifically *want* to use the participle (which would be associated here with formal writing: good for legal use, questionable for academic writing, poor style for literature)

Comment: "Ставить перед фактом" usually means leaving someone with no choice, it is not a good translation of "to confront with the fact". And the passive voice (страдательный залог) often sounds especially stilted in Russian.

Answer (score 2):

*Предъявлять* or *уличать* might work, depending on context (not synonyms).

This translation might work, although I think it sounds a little awkward because the word факт is referring to the subjective experience of the speaker:

*Я предъявил ему тот факт, что видел, как он входил в здание.*

Or this, although it may be too liberal:

*Я уличил его в том, что он входил в здание*

Finally, you could translate it something like this (also liberal):

*Я сказал ему (в лицо), что видел, как он входил в здание*

Can't think of anything better at the moment, none of these is perfect.\

Comment: +1. Можно еще сказать "указал на тот факт, что".

Comment: Yes, but "указал" does not necessarily imply confrontation. The reverse translation would be "pointed out".

Comment: `уличить` is not neutral. In the example, however, it seems to fit.

Answer (score 0):

"ставить перед фактом" is very common. (reveal smth before him, for he will be reduced with the remain options. literally "put him before the fact").

> I confronted him with the fact, [of] that I've seen him entering the building.
>   Я поставил его перед фактом того, что я видел его входящим в здание.
>   He was confronted with the fact, [of] that somebody has seen him entering the building.
>   Он был поставлен перед фактом [того], что кто-то видел его входящим в здание.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these sentences were preceded with 'him' claiming that he had not been inside that building, I suggest the following translations:

> I confronted him with the fact, that I've seen him entering the building.

- Я возразил ему, сказав, что видел, как он входил в здание.

`Возразить` means 'to object, to retort' and it's weaker than 'to confront'. The closest expression I can think of would be `дать отпор` but it's a bit outdated:

- Я дал ему отпор, сказав, что видел, как он входил в здание.

One could also use `загнать в угол` 'to corner' but obviously the meaning is a bit different:

- Я загнал его в угол, сказав, что видел, как он входил в здание.

Out of the above, I would stick with `возразить`, `возражение`.

> He was confronted with the fact, that somebody has seen him entering the building.

- В ответ он получил возражение в виде того факта, что его видели входящим в здание.

Answer (score 0):

I think we could deal just with adverbs or quasiadverbal structures combined with ***Ho*** in beginning of a phrase, e. g.:

***Но я сказал ему, что, напротив / на самом деле /фактически / видел, как он заходил/заходит в здание.***

***Но кто-то /на самом деле /фактически /, напротив, /  видел, как он заходил/заходит в здание.***